# Capacitor with n electrodes

Tags: capacitor, capacitance

In my book it says that the capacitance in a capacitor with n electrodes is (n-1)*Co, Co is a capacitance of a two parallel plates capacitor. I know how to distribute charge when there are 3 parallel plates( two of them are connected to single Q,and the third which is in the middle to -Q), and I get 2*Co, but I can't figure out how to distribute charge when there are four of them.

Comment: Assuming the plates are connected in an interleaved fashion as normal, there are n-1 gaps with n electrodes. Each one acts as a capacitor in parallel with the others.

Comment: Okay, I'll make it an answer and expand on it a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the plates are connected in an interleaved fashion as normal, there are n-1 gaps with n electrodes. Each one acts as a capacitor in parallel with the others.

Here is an image from [this](http://www.itacanet.org/basic-electrical-engineering/part-7-capacitance-and-capacitors/) website.

[image: http://www.itacanet.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/cap-600x294.jpg]

You can see that there are 11 plates and 10 gaps resulting in effectively 10 parallel capacitors of area equal (approximately) to the area of the dielectric slabs.

Comment: If I may ask you one more thing. What if three capacitors were long wirees, and first and third are connectd. How would that affect potential and charge distribution?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.. the plates are wires?

Comment: Yes, instead of 3 parallel plates, there are 3 parallel wires. I need capacitance of a system like that and I don't know how does this connection affects voltage. If this requires any calcutaions, ignore

Comment: Capacitance between wires is much more complex. The middle wires won't shield the outer wires from each other the way the plates will. It's either a fairly complex calculation or a field solver simulation I think.

Comment: This is just entry level electronis and outer wires are connected, that means that potential difference is 0, and that implies that field between them is also 0. Right?

Comment: Yes. But even for three wires there will be a complex field .. even for [two wires](http://images.tutorvista.com/cms/images/101/dipole-electric-field.png) it's not simple. The field between plates of the flat-plate capacitor by contrast can be accurately approximated by evenly spaced straight parallel lines.